# Regex : negative pattern in a filename

Tags: regex, linux

Yesterday I pulled off my hair on a problem :

I own an ecommerce website and I want to delete some products thumbnails not useful anymore
on my linux web server I would like to target them with a "find iregex '...' -exec rm " commande line to wipe them all

Here are some products name example all in the same directory :

```
product.name-350x350.jpg
product.name-50x50.jpg
productname-120x120.jpg
product-name-120x120.jpg
product-name.jpg
product-name-120.jpg
product-name-120px.jpg
```

the sub pattern that indicates it is a thumbnail is :

`-AAAAxAAAA.jpg`  with AAAA a digit from 1 to 4 cars length

So only the 4 firts lines of the examples are thumbnails
I'm find a regex to wipe all the jpeg that are thumbnails subpattern

It is :

```
-iregex '-([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4}).jpg'
```

But for the game, I asked myself the question "how to find all the products name that are NOT thumbnails ?"

I tried with no results :

```
[^(0-9{1,4}x0-9{1,4}.)]
```

And read a lot about negative regex without finding a solution.
Can you help ?

Sebastien.

Comment: something like this `^[A-Za-z_.-]+\d*?\.jpg$`  check here https://regex101.com/r/U6OMei/1

Comment: Instead of `-exec rm {} \;`, it is preferable to simply use `-delete`.

Comment: @Code Maniac  Almost ! this one is not targeted: product-name-120px.jpg

Comment: @code-maniac Yes your demo links does not highlight this one : product-name-120px.jpg  This one is not a thumbnail. only the 4 First of my list.

Comment: @SebastienR. yeah i missed that one. https://regex101.com/r/U6OMei/2 check this one

Comment: @Code Maniac Nice  ! It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^xxx]` is a negative *character class*. It has no internal structure. `[^ABC]` and `[^CBA]` are the same thing: *"Anything except the characters 'A', 'B', or 'C'"*. So these things don't quite work the way you assume.

Negative matching is generally much harder<sup>(*)</sup> with regex, typically it's easier to negate externally, i.e. match with the regex, but exclude matches in the tool that uses the regex.

To negate a condition, `find` has `-not`:

```
find -type f -regextype posix-extended -not -iregex '.*-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}\.jpg'
```

Since pure blacklisting is dangerous (you could end up matching things you did not have in mind), you should combine a positive pattern (*"all pictures..."*) and an exclusion pattern (*"...except those"*) using the logical operators `find` supports.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The most convenient way to exclude matches in regex are so-called negative [lookaheads/lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). These constructs are not supported by `find` as far as I know.

Comment: THanks @Tomalak . I thought the answer makes sense. But strangely, on my webserver your code line returns every pictures names.with or without thumbnail pattern  ! here is the full code : `find /home/path/images -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -iregex '.*-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}\.jpg' -print`

Comment: Get deeper and find the problem : I had to add `-regextype posix-extended` to get it return the correct results. Thanks Tomalak!

Comment: You're right, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `regex` with `sed` command. This will allow you to avoid to print the matches, using the `D`.

Give a try to this:

```
find . -type f -iregex '.*[.]jpg' | sed '/-[1-9][0-9]\{0,3\}x[1-9][0-9]\{0,3\}[.]jpg$/D'
```

**Output**

```
./product-name.jpg
./product-name-120px.jpg
./product-name-120.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. Well noted to delete the files. Before that I try to show all the NOT thumbnails pictures.

Comment: @SebastienR. this what the command line is doing.